# Python looping through specific element in list

Tags: python, for-loop

I have two lists in following manner and I am trying to compare them in some specific style:

```
a = [[18, 299, 559], [18, 323, 564], [18, 353, 564], [18, 391, 570], [18, 448, 570]]

b = [[18, 353, 564], [18, 299, 559], [18, 323, 564], [18, 391, 570], [18, 448, 570]]
```

**What I want**

I want to compare every element of `a` with `b` in following order.

For instance, in above case after first element `[18, 299, 559]` of `a` equals `[18, 299, 559]` of `b`, the loop will break and in the new loop 2nd element of `a` i.e `[18, 323, 564]` will be compared from `[18, 323, 564]` of `b` and onwards.

The point here is that new loop should not start again iterating from first element of `b`while comparing all elements of `a` individually with all of `b` from 0th index.

**P.S.** In this example I am not trying to check the existence of elements in both lists, or finding any missing elements which can be easily done by using `set` method. This logic is just for my own knowledge

**What I tried**

All ordinary nested loop methods like below:

```
for i in a:
    for j in b: #after break it would always start with first element in b
        if i == j:
            break
```

the problem here is after every `break` new `i` is compared from first element of `b` and not from last element which was matched with `a`

Something which is going through my mind looks like this:

```
for i in a:
    for j in b: 
        if i == j:
           print something
           save index of j 
           break

        in the next loop start comparing new i from this saved index of j
```

yet, I am not able to put this idea into code though.

I know this sounds absurd but can something like this be implemented in python as far as looping is concern? All ideas and hints are welcomed.

Comment: Have you tried `continue` instead of `break`?

Comment: @lanAuld no i did not. Let me have a look

Comment: [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip)

Comment: @LanAuld tried replacing `break` with `continue` in above code but still not getting what i want. Can you highlight a little how i should use it?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger using zip two loops would iterate in parallel fashion. which would just compare both elements line wise.

Comment: I'm gonna have to support the `continue` option where you just append the pair if indices to a list when a match is found. It's easy, short, and pythonic.

Comment: @DhruvJ "in the next loop start comparing new i from this saved index of j" isn't that trying to emulate zip ?

Comment: @MathiasEttinger yes you are right but in that case i wont be able to check each of element of `a` individually with `b`

Comment: @Aaron I l try again with continue more accurately. Thanks for suggestion. It sounds short and specific.

Comment: I actually just did a quickie without either... see below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you could just trace how far you've come in `b`. I'll call this variable `start_j`, from there on it is allowed to start comparing in `b`:

```
a = [[18, 299, 559], [18, 323, 564], [18, 353, 564], [18, 391, 570], [18, 448, 570]]
b = [[18, 353, 564], [18, 299, 559], [18, 323, 564], [18, 391, 570], [18, 448, 570]]

start_j = 0

for i in range(len(a)):
    for j in range(start_j, len(b)):
        if a[i] == b[j]:
            print 'match found:', i, j
            start_j = j
            break
```

If matching elements have been found, `start_j` is set to the newest `j` and the next time the inner loop (for checking elements in `b`) starts there.

Output:

```
match found: 0 1
match found: 1 2
match found: 3 3
match found: 4 4
```

Comment: this is so elegant! I thought it would be rather complicated

Comment: It's mainly what you had in mind (the code at the bottom of your question). The only difference is the looping through 0, 1, 2... instead of the elements themselves (`for i in a`), so you have explicit access on which index you are.

Comment: Yes. This exactly matches with it. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
start_idx = 0
for i in a:
    for j_idx, j in enumerate(b[start_idx:], start=start_idx):
        if j==a:
            print 'Bingo!'
            start_idx = j_idx
            break
```

P.S range(len(a)) - it's ugly :)

Comment: it's not that ugly, but xrange _is_ a better option if you're using 2.7... (than range to be specific)

Comment: I think my version faster anyway

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it without continue or beak...

```
a = [[18, 299, 559], [18, 323, 564], [18, 353, 564], [18, 391, 570], [18, 448, 570]]

b = [[18, 353, 564], [18, 299, 559], [18, 323, 564], [18, 391, 570], [18, 448, 570]]

matches = []

for i in xrange(len(a)):
    for j in xrange(len(b)):
        if a[i] == b[j]:
            matches.append([i,j])

for match in matches: print(match)
```

Comment: I was just trying it out. Thank you Aaron.

Comment: No problems, it's always great to learn many different ways to do something.

Comment: I would never have thought to use a `set()` but @Hai_Vu provided quite an interesting solution.

Comment: Yes it directly lists out differences and missing elements. its useful but I was more curious about the method i mentioned. I was struggling to implement so that's why asked.

Answer (score 0):

From your description:

> P.S. In this example I am not trying to check the existence of elements in both lists, or finding any missing elements which can be easily done by using set method. This logic is just for my own knowledge

I think you are trying to do a set comparison between the two lists. Why not turning them into sets?

```
aset = set(tuple(item) for item in a)
bset = set(tuple(item) for item in b)

print 'Items only in A:', aset - bset
print 'Items only in B:', bset - aset
print 'Items in common:', aset & bset
```

Note: I have to turn each sub-list into a tuple since a list is not hashable, thus cannot be in a set.

Comment: I know this method as i mentioned in P.S. but i wanted to know whether we can save j's status and use it for further iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If both of your lists have the same element or you don't know this might be a efficient yet not elegant solution. (I agree the range(len(a)) is ugly)

```
a = [[18, 299, 559], [18, 323, 564], [18, 353, 564], [18, 391, 570], [18, 448, 570]]

b = [[18, 353, 564], [18, 299, 559], [18, 323, 564], [18, 391, 570], [18, 448, 570]]

# You will compare the length of the list that is the shortest and use that length to iterate over the elements
if (len(a) <= len (b)):
    index_same_elements = []
    len_lists = len(a)
    for i in range(len_lists):
        if a[i]==b[i]:
            print(f'For the index {i}, element in a is equal to the element in b')
            index_same_elements.append(i)

else:
    index_same_elements = []
    len_lists = len(b)
    for i in range(len_lists):
        if a[i]==b[i]:
            print(f'For the index {i}, element in a is equal to the element in b')
            index_same_elements.append(i)
```

The index_same_elements will allow you to identify which elements are the same in both lists. Hope it helps someone reading this 7 years after lol

Comment: Thanks for the post. However, it seems the implementation does not fully meet the question requirements.